# In Vue, which watcher will be called first? A deep watch on an object, or a watch on a property of that object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have the following Vue object, and myObj.myProp1 is changed, which watcher will be called first? What determines the order and is there any way to manipulate the order?

```js
new Vue({
    data: {
        myObj: {
            myProp1: "one",
            myProp2: "two"
        }
    },
    computed: {
        myProp1: function () { return this.myObj.myProp1; }
    },
    watch: {
        myProp1: function () { alert("myProp1 Changed") },
        myObj: {
            handler: function () { alert("myObj Changed") },
            deep: true
        }
    }
})
```

When I tested it, the watcher pointing to the property was called first, but I want to make sure that it wasn't a fluke and dependent on other things in my code that I might not be aware of.

Is it just the order in which the watchers are listed in the watcher segment of the Vue object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the initialization of watchers is the same order that the [`for-in` statement works](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#enumerating-the-string-keys-of-all-enumerable-properties).

The watchers of a component are initialized in the [`initState` function](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.10/src/core/instance/state.js#L60) which is invoked when [initializing the component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.10/src/core/instance/init.js#L57).

The properties of the `watch` object are enumerated using the `for-in` statement as you can see [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.10/src/core/instance/state.js#L291):

```
function initWatch (vm: Component, watch: Object) {
  for (const key in watch) { // <- watch object properties enumerated here
    const handler = watch[key]
    if (Array.isArray(handler)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < handler.length; i++) {
        createWatcher(vm, key, handler[i])
      }
    } else {
      createWatcher(vm, key, handler)
    }
  }
```

For more information about the traversal order of properties in JavaScript, check the following article:

- [The traversal order of object properties in ES6](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html)